# Checking if Firefox uses hardware accelearation

Tags: firefox, browser, hardware-acceleration

I was measuring the performance of my application on Firefox.

I have seen the change in performance depending on hardware acceleration setting on chrome so I also tried it on Firefox.

However, unlike chrome, there was no performance change between Firefox with hw acceleration and Firefox without hw acceleration

So I was wondering if I did something wrong or this is expected behavior.
Is there a way to check if firefox is using hardware acceleration other than check box in setting?

I have Ubuntu 18 and version of firefox is 62.0.3

p.s. I have also enabled layers.acceleration.force-enabled to true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that webGL is enabled on Firefox and disabled on Chrome by default

Also, if hardware acc is disabled on chrome, webGL gets disabled as well on Chrome.
On the other hand, even though hardware acc is disabled, if webGL is enabled on fiefox, it does use webGL